# How to center the title in ionic3 on all devices

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I add a navbar which adds a back arrow button and a button to the right my header gets right aligned, and also is not responsive.
How to make it in center and responsive on all devices be it android or iphone.

**.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Page1</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button clear class="header-buttons" (click)="goToFollowersPage()">Get followers</button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

**.css**

```
.toolbar-md,.toolbar-ios {
        min-height: 40px;
        padding: 0;
    }

.toolbar-title-md,.toolbar-title-ios {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.header-buttons {
    color: #4A90E2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 19px;
    opacity: 1.0;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: initial;
}

ion-title {
   width: 275px;
   margin-left: auto;
   padding-left: 65px;
}
ion-buttons {
   margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's the solution, but i suggest not using the `<ion-toolbar>` inside the `<ion-navbar>`. Usually only `<ion-navbar>` is enough.

Comment: what if I have to use ion-buttons ? Don't I need the toolbar then ?And then when would the toolbar be used?

Comment: You can use buttons in a navbar, as explained [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Navbar/). A toolbar could also be used, but in this case, as you need the navigation button (arrow back), the navbar seems more appropriate.

Comment: okay will try and update it soon

Answer (score 0):

For me, using just `ion-navbar` without `ion-toolbar` also didnt align the title. I used a walkaround by changing my css.

For your css, use this 2 styles:

```
ion-title {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 90px 1px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.toolbar-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

This will make your title always align to center